# How to play a slurred Portato with damper pedal?

Tags: piano

Extract is The Reef by Walter Carroll.

How would one play the slurred (accented) Portato well with damper pedal without cutting off the sound?[image]

The following are found in one of the YT tutorial for this piece:
"There are many staccato markings in this piece, which strangely are at the same time as pedal markings, which effectively "neutralizes" any staccato effect. Therefore, the purpose of these markings is to indicate the type of touch needed, rather than the acoustic effect achieved."

PS: I posted with due respect for the OP of the YT tutorial.

Comment: The post you quoted is correct. The finger touch is as though you're playing staccato, but while holding the pedal. There is a subtle difference in sound that if you were playing more legato, particularly at the note onset. Try playing both ways to see if your ear detects the difference. Just know it takes experience for it to become clear (or even detectable).

Comment: This was a piece in ABRSM piano exams a couple of years ago. I spoke with ABRSM, who didn't really come up with anything useful. So it wasn't used for the candidate! My answer was to *half-pedal*, which then gives the desired effect, although at grade V (I think) that would not be a known technique.